# How to count the average word number in a line?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have a text file that has one sentence per line stored and I would like to know how many words in average a sentence (a line in this file) has. How can I do that?

Also, how to count the number of unique words in that file, and the number of common unique words in two such files?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `the number of unique words between two such files` has a couple of possible meanings and even `word` is ambiguous. Please [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input, expected output, and your attempt to solve the problem yourself. See [ask].

Comment: How do you define a *word*? How many word's in `It's 2+2 = 3 again-and-again?!` for instance?

Comment: This might be better asked as two questions, not one?

Answer (score 4):

`wc file` will show you the number of lines, words, and bytes in the given `file`; the ratio of words to lines will give you the average number of words per line.

To count the number of unique words, split the file up into one word (here, anything separated by one or more spaces) per line, sort it and count the number of unique words:

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' < file | sort -u | wc -l
```

If you need to remove punctuation, you’ll need to filter the result before the sort (*e.g.* using `tr` to remove unwanted characters).

To count words which are unique to two files, you can use `comm`:

```
comm -3 <(tr -s ' ' '\n' < file1 | sort -u) <(tr -s ' ' '\n' < file2 | sort -u)
```

will list words which only appear in `file1` or `file2` but not both.

```
comm -12 <(tr -s ' ' '\n' < file1 | sort -u) <(tr -s ' ' '\n' < file2 | sort -u)
```

will list words which appear in both files, piping that to `wc -l` will count them.

To count unique words across multiple files, concatenate them before feeding them to `tr`:

```
cat file1 file2 | tr -s ' ' '\n' | sort -u | wc -l
```

Comment: Thanks, for the last one maybe I did not explain it well, I  meant to count the number of common unique words in two files.

Comment: OK, see the update.

Comment: The size of the file won’t make any difference to the above, all the commands here can deal with large amounts of data.

Comment: I'd agree with Stephen, you really need to go into the millions of words for things to matter, but of course, a shell script sorting words is not as efficient as something checking for whether a word is already in a clever set-like data structure. You might want to write 10 lines of Python instead – but: how big is "extremely big"? When I advise students, they tend to think 10000 of something is "very many", and my computer tends to disagree. If your files are larger than 1GB, we're talking about "much data". Big data starts much larger...

Comment: Thanks guys, i got it now. Only still the last part not, because this line: cat file1 file2 | xargs -n1 | sort -u | wc -l gives me unique words in total from a file made from both files, but only the words that appear in one and another file.  I need to get the number of unique words that appear in both files ( so to say to see how similar are te files in the end)

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify exactly what you’re looking for. I’ve added another `comm` variant which counts words which appear in both files.

Answer (score 1):

This can print the average number of words of each line:

```bsh
wc input.txt | awk '{print $2 / $1}'
```

Your question is ambiguous and requires refinement. Don't know if it can really solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Counting words using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -e 'my @a.=push($_.words.elems) for lines; say @a; put @a.sum; put @a.elems; put @a.sum / @a.elems;'
```

Sample Input:

```
the
the of
the of and
the of and in
the of and in a
the of and in a is
the of and in a is that
the of and in a is that for
the of and in a is that for it
the of and in a is that for it as
```

Sample Output:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
55
10
5.5
```

Above is an answer coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Briefly, `lines` are looped over using `for` and loaded into the Perl/Raku `$_` topic variable. An array `@a` is declared and `$_` input is `push`-ed onto it in one go using the `.=` operator [a shortcut for `@a = @a.push($_.words.elems)`]. The actual value pushed onto the `@a` array is the number of words, because each line is broken into `.words` and counted with `.elems`. Finally, output is produced with `sum`, `elems`, and then `sum`-divided_by- `elems` to get an average.

To always output the full machine-representation of an object, use `put`. Using `say` will provide a more human-readable summary of a Raku object (truncating after 99-elements).

[ For counting unique words, there are a few approaches. See `unique` at the link below. ]

https://docs.raku.org/routine/unique
https://raku.org